# django No module named article.models

Tags: python, django

i found so many question about these on stack overflow. but check it all .i think i have no fault about these but.its't work.....

tree .root is my_blog

```
|____airticle
| |______init__.py
| |______init__.pyc
| |____admin.py
| |____admin.pyc
| |____migrations
| | |____0001_initial.py
| | |____0001_initial.pyc
| | |______init__.py
| | |______init__.pyc
| |____models.py
| |____models.pyc
| |____tests.py
| |____views.py
|____db.sqlite3
|____manage.py
|____my_blog
| |______init__.py
| |______init__.pyc
| |____settings.py
| |____settings.pyc
| |____urls.py
| |____urls.pyc
| |____wsgi.py
| |____wsgi.pyc
```

every catalogs above __ init__.py

and settting install_app

## Application definition

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'airticle',
)
```

models

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100) ##博客题目
  category = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)#博客标签
  date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)#博客正文
  def __unicode__(self):
    return selft.title

    class Meta:#按时间下降排序
      ordering = ['-data_time']
```

and models can create the database and table 
but when i into python shell , and input 
from article models import Article .i just get a error "No module named article.models"

and i use django1.8 and python 2.7

Comment: is that a typo or your app is named `airticle`?

Comment: app name airticle.. something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply misspelled the python module name.  Try `from airticle import models`.